# How to avoid the update of List elements

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code to copy the New Record from Previous record based on Id.

```
 //selecting the employee to be copied.
 Employee emp=employeeList.Where(p=>p.Id==2).Single();

 //Increasing the Employee Id.
 Employee NewEmp=new Employee();
 NewEmp=emp;
 NewEmp.Id=employeeList.Max(p=>p.Id)+1;

 //Adding to the List.
 employeeList.Add(NewEmp);
```

however the New Record has been added successfully. The existing Record Id has also been changed to New Max Id 3 since it is context.

could you please someone help me to stop updating the exisiting record object.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Employee` and then setting the reference to the old `Employee`?

Comment: Try to read about reference types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx @khellang: because he thinks, that assigning of a reference will make a copy of data.

Comment: @Sravan, check out object cloning in C# (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
Employee NewEmp=new Employee();
NewEmp=emp;
```

You create new object (first line), then (second line) assign "emp" in variable NewEmp, and now they both reference to the same object, so actually you work with one object. New Employee you created actually will be collected by GC.

U can learn more from difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

The allocation you do here:

```
Employee NewEmp=new Employee();
```

is completely ineffective and the new instance is abandoned by the immediatelly following line:

```
NewEmp=emp;
```

You have to copy the contents of `emp` field-by-field (property-by-property). In your case I would recommend implementing `ICloneable` on `Employee` — [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) for documetation.

Another options include:

- declaring `Employee` as a struct;
- using [Object.MemberwiseClone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx).

However, I don't receommend either way in respect to your anticipated skill-level.

---

Note: It is a common practice to start the names of local variables with a lower-case letter, e.g. 'newEmp'.

Comment: > In your case I would recommend implementing IClonable - I wouldn't recommend to implement `ICloneable` anywhere. `ICloneable` is a thing, that should not be.

Comment: @Dennis Any supportive thoughts for your statement in respect to the OP's situation?

Comment: O-O-mappers are intended for things, which OP want to do.

Comment: @Dennis The OP doesn't even understand the notion of references. How could you then recommend using a technology which will be close to nuclear reactor engineering from his point of view? That is ridiculous. He's apparently a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the old `Employee` to the `NewEmp` variable and updating the `NewEmp.Id` to 3. Then you are adding the same `Employee` to the list again. So you have two of the same `Employee`s with `Id = 3` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
newEmp = emp;
```

does not copy `emp`. It just creates a new reference to the same location in memory. So effectively `emp` and `newEmp` are one and the same, but not two separate memory blocks. Read up on "reference types", e.g. here: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx